# Get the 'Content Permission' roles as defined in a page

Tags: pages, permissions

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have assigned `student level 1` to a Page in WP admin. I am building a custom `page.php` on my own and I am trying to redirect the user back if they were not added.

I try with

```
if (!current_user_can('read_post'))
```

But obviously, all users and read a Page. What I am tryint to accomplish is somethinng like

```
current_user_is_in_content_permissions() ? display() : redirect_back();
```

How can write the code in my `pages.php`

WP automatically displays

> Sorry, but you do not have permission to view this content.